# How to project an image, and bake it so to speak, on an angled plane

Tags: materials, uv

How to project a non distorted image, Say this is the background image, and bake it so to speak on an angled plane.

so when the camera is placed just right, it looks Just like the original Rendered:

[image]

But when you press seven and you looking at it so you’re looking straight down, it looks baked like this:[image]

Basically without going through all the rigmarole of having a plan to Do shadow catching and glossy reflecting and such I just want to take a snapshot of the rendered image with the background and then project that on an angled plane. That way I can just set my stuff on that plane and get the shadows in whatever...
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "Project from view" option from the unwrap menu. That will project the uvs of your object to match the dimensions of your camera.
Create a plane an subdivide it a number of times. Place a camera so that it faces the plane at an angle and there is no empty space within the render frame.

[image]

Remember to set your render dimensions to the same ones of your reference image. Example 350 * 350

[image]

While in edit mode, press  <kbd>u</kbd> or click on "UV" on the topbar and choose "Project from view".

Create a new material and assign it to your plane. Now add an "Image texture" node and plug it into the color of your shader. Select your image. Set it to "Clip" so that it doesn't repeat outside the camera view.

[image]

Result from the camera view <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>:

[image]

And from top view <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> :

[image]

Comment: You are Gorgious!